# The same VS separate email adresses for website system and Newsletter Service

Tags: php, html-email, email, email-client

I have one email adress for my website: contact@mywebsite.com.

from this email, the site sends 
- email adress confirmation emails when a new account has been created, 
- password recovery emails, 
- recieves an email when a new account has been created,
- and other automatical emails like notification for the affiliates when a user joined from their link, etc...

I also use this email with Mailchimp for a Mass Newsletter Service.

My question is... does the fact that I use Mailchimp and send emails to hundreds of adresses might stop the email adress from working properly in the website system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter. It is good practice though to email your subscriber lists (mass emails) from a separate email address to the one you use everyday.

One reason is that you can get pretty bogged down with out of office replies. Another reason is just in case the unthinkable happens and you get blacklisted or your deliverability is affected somehow. Usually blacklisting is on an IP address/domain level, but I've had issues in the past where a different address on the same domain and IP can end up in the junk folder while another hits the inbox with the exact same email content. Blacklisting and/or ending up in junkmail can occasionally happen to legitimate email marketers, so it is good to not 'keep all your eggs in one basket'.